# Amend javascript to also remove string

Tags: javascript, replace, find

```
$(document).on("knack-view-render.view_335", function (event, view, data) {
$('#field_134').attr('maxLength', 26);
});
```

currently use the above code to restrict the length of the input text, but I'd also like to same code to in addition detect an inputted string of "in stock" or "is in stock" and replace with "AMEND INPUT" or similar.

Any ideas?!

many thanks

Comment: What kind of event is "knack-view-render.view_335"?

Comment: it's from the knack online database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I did not know you custom event, I just came up with this

```
$(document).on("knack-view-render.view_335", function (event, view, data) {
let input = $('#field_134');
let inputted = "";
let notAllowed1 = "in stock";
let notAllowed2 = "is in stock";

input.attr('maxLength', 26);
input.on("change paste keyup", function() {
inputted = $(this).val(); 
if (inputted.includes(notAllowed1 || notAllowed2)) {
  $(this).val("AMEND INPUT")
};
});
});
```