# javascript OR operation doesn't seem to work beyond first two options

Tags: javascript, replace

Attempting to modify [some fantastic code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66613624?noredirect=1) but finding my modifications aren't working...

```
$(document).on("knack-view-render.view_335", function (event, view, data) {
let input = $('#field_134');
let inputted = "";
let notAllowed1 = "in stock";
let notAllowed2 = "is in stock";
let notAllowed3 = "In stock";
let notAllowed4 = "are in stock";  
let notAllowed5 = "are here";
let notAllowed6 = "In Stock";
let notAllowed7 = "is here";
let notAllowed8 = "IN STOCK";

input.attr('maxLength', 26);
input.on("change paste keyup", function() {
inputted = $(this).val(); 
if (inputted.includes(notAllowed1 || notAllowed2 || notAllowed3 || notAllowed4 || notAllowed5 || notAllowed6 || notAllowed7 || notAllowed8)) {
  $(this).val("PLEASE JUST NAME THE ITEM...")
};
});
});
```

The first two test OK, but none of the following seem to match? Thank you!!!

Comment: Hate to b̶r̶i̶n̶g̶ break it to you, but your "fantastic code" isn't working. You copied broken code.

Comment: Shame about the snark - and no, I didn't. It works. Until I modify it.
P.S. It's not "bring it to you" but "break it to you" !

Comment: Thanks, i enjoy these corrections, otherwise i'd continue doing such mistakes again and again. The code you copied still doesn't work as intended.

Comment: That's not how the `||` operator works. You have do perform a separate `.includes()` test for each of those "notAllowed" values individually.

Comment: Thank you Pointy for spotting what ASDFGerte failed to. Much appreciated.

Comment: To be completely clear: `.includes(notAllowed1 || notAllowed2)`, where `notAllowed1` and `notAllowed2` are non-empty strings, is identical to `.includes(notAllowed1)`. It doesn't do what's intended at all. The related answer is wrong, and causing the problems here - you extrapolate from faulty information. See the [MDN page about logical or](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) for reference.

Comment: ASDFGerte  - I really don't - I am testing and have tested the code you assert is faulty and non-working and it works both beautifully and as intended. I am just trying to expand it.

Comment: it works, because `"in stock"` is a substring of `"is in stock"`, and the second test is completely redundant. Omitting it therefore just doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: Fair enough - you're right about that and I hadn't spotted it. I've amended (bodged) the code so that it's basically a long list of 'if' statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go building an array of not allowed things, then use `includes` within you input value, something like:

```js
const notAllowed = ['in stock', 'are in stock', 'is here'];
const inputted = 'are in stock';

const isAllowed = notAllowed.includes(inputted);

if (isAllowed) {
  console.log(isAllowed);
}
```